# How to list objects in Google Cloud Storage from PHP

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-api-php-client

I am trying to list objects in a folder within a Google Cloud Storage bucket. I can get a result with 1000 objects easily (or increase the number if I want) using the following code:

```
$names = [];
$bucket = $client->bucket('mybucketname');
$options = ['prefix' => 'myfoldername', 'fields' =>' items/name,nextPageToken'];
$objects = $bucket->objects($options);
foreach ($objects as $object) {
  $names[] = $object->name();
}
```

So far so good, but now I want to get the next 1000 objects (or whatever limit I set using `maxResults` and `resultLimit`) using the fact that I specified the `nextPageToken` object. I know that I have to do this by specifying `pageToken` as an option - it's just that I have no idea how.

I expect my final code will look something like this - what I need is the line of code which retrieves the next page token.

```
$names = [];
$bucket = $client->bucket('mybucketname');
$options = ['prefix' => 'myfoldername', 'fields' =>' items/name,nextPageToken'];
while(true) {
  $objects = $bucket->objects($options);
  foreach ($objects as $object) {
    $names[] = $object->name();
  }
  $nextPageToken = $objects->getNextPageTokenSomehowOrOther(); // @todo Need help here!!!!!!!
  if (empty($objects) || empty($nextPageToken)){
    break;
  }
  $options['pageToken'] = $nextPageToken;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The nextPageToken is the name of the last object of the first request encoded in Base64.

Here we have an example from the documentation:

```
{
  "kind": "storage#objects",
  "nextPageToken": "CgtzaGliYS0yLmpwZw==",
  "items": [
    objects Resource
    …
  ]
}
```

If you decode the value "CgtzaGliYS0yLmpwZw==" this will reveal the value "shiba-2.jpg"

Here we have the definition of PageToken based on API documentation:

> The pageToken is an encoded field that marks the name and generation of the last
> object in the returned list. In a subsequent request using the pageToken, items
> that come after the pageToken are shown (up to maxResults).

References:

- https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list#parameters
- https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/paginate-results#rest-paginate-results

See ya

Comment: That may be correct information, but it doesn't help explain what to do in the PHP library. But checking again, my PHP library now seems to be returning all results if I don't specify maxResults or pageLimit, rather than just returning the first 1000 results like it did before. I'm not sure I understand what's happening, but at least it's now working...